# Remove content from two html tags

Tags: html, regex, notepad++, head

i have aprox. 200 files with different content in `<head> </head>`. I want to replace it and leave it with nothing.

Is there a regular expression for Notepad++ or something like that?

I had this regular expression:

```
<head>[^<>]+</head>
```

But for some reason (that i don't know) it doesn't works in these files.

Comment: Show us what you want to find and replace.  The regex you showed us might be suitable for replacing the contents of the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^<>]+` means to match one or more characters *other than* `<` or `>`. That is, the full regular expression that you show is looking for `<head>` followed by some non `<` and `>` characters, followed by `</head>`.

But most HTML documents will have a `<head>` element that contains `<` and `>` characters in order to define other elements like `<title>` and so forth, so your regex will not match those.

Try this:

```
<head>.+</head>
```

I.e., use `.+` to match *any* characters in between the opening `<head>` and closing `</head>`. Then in Notepad++'s Find/Replace window make sure you've selected the "Regular expression" radio button and ticked the ". matches newline" checkbox. If you also want to match completely empty `<head>` elements then change `.+` to `.*`.